# Back space function for python gui calculator to clear most recent input for example 435 delete 5 and show 43

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda, backspace

I would like some help making a backspace button function where when pressed it removes and clears the last number inputted for example if i have 561 and i press the button it clears the 1 and shows 56 if anyone could help me make this backspace function it would be great and highly appreciated. Everything is formated and fine all i need is the backspace to work so when i press it the last number showing in the top display clears

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)


screen = StringVar()
screen.set("0")

current = ""
power = ""
expression = ""

firstnum = str()
secondnum = str()
mathsign = str()

defxworking = False
percentt = False


def math_button_pressed():
    if mathsign == "+":
        button_plus.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    if mathsign == "-":
        button_minus.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    if mathsign == "*":
        button_multiply.config(relief=SUNKEN)
    if mathsign == "/":
        button_division.config(relief=SUNKEN)


def math_button_raised():
    button_plus.config(relief=RAISED)
    button_minus.config(relief=RAISED)
    button_multiply.config(relief=RAISED)
    button_division.config(relief=RAISED)


def is_int(num):
    if int(num) == float(num):
        return int(num)
    else:
        return float(num)


def number_pressed(butt):
    global current, power, firstnum, secondnum

    if mathsign == str() and defxworking == False:
        current = current + str(butt)
        screen.set(current)
        firstnum = float(current)

    elif mathsign != str() and defxworking == False:
        math_button_raised()
        current = current + str(butt)
        screen.set(current)
        secondnum = float(current)

    elif mathsign == str() and defxworking == True:
        power = power + str(butt)
        current = current + str(butt)
        screen.set(current)

    elif mathsign != str and defxworking == True:
        power = power + str(butt)
        current = current + str(butt)
        screen.set(current)
        print(power)


def math_pressed(math):
    global current, power, mathsign, firstnum, secondnum, defxworking, percentt

    if (
            mathsign == str()
            and defxworking == False
            and percentt == False
            and firstnum != str()
    ):
        mathsign = str(math)
        math_button_pressed()
        current = ""

    elif mathsign != str() and defxworking == False and percentt == False:
        print(2)
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum + secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum - secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "*":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum * secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "/":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum / secondnum), 6)
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))

        mathsign = str(math)
        math_button_pressed()
        current = ""

    elif mathsign != str() and defxworking == True and percentt == False:
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(firstnum + secondnum ** int(power), 6)
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(firstnum - secondnum ** int(power), 6)
        if mathsign == "*":
            firstnum = round(firstnum * (secondnum ** int(power)), 6)
        if mathsign == "/":
            firstnum = round(firstnum / (secondnum ** int(power)), 6)
        defxworking = False
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))
        defxworking = False
        mathsign = str(math)
        math_button_pressed()
        power = ""
        current = ""

    elif defxworking and percentt == False:
        firstnum = round(firstnum ** int(power), 6)
        defxworking = False
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))
        mathsign = str(math)
        math_button_pressed()
        power = ""
        current = ""

    elif percentt:
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum + firstnum / 100 * secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum - firstnum / 100 * secondnum), 6)
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))
        percentt = False
        mathsign = str(math)
        math_button_pressed()
        current = ""


def squareroot():
    global firstnum, secondnum, mathsign, current

    if mathsign == str():
        firstnum = round(sqrt(firstnum), 6)
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))

    if mathsign != str():
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(sqrt(firstnum + float(secondnum)), 6)
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(sqrt(firstnum - float(secondnum)), 6)
        if mathsign == "*":
            firstnum = round(sqrt(firstnum * float(secondnum)), 6)
        if mathsign == "/":
            firstnum = round(sqrt(firstnum / float(secondnum)), 6)

        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))
        secondnum = str()
        mathsign = str()
        current = ""


def x():
    global firstnum, secondnum, mathsign, current, defxworking

    if mathsign == str():
        current = str(is_int(firstnum)) + "^"
        screen.set(current)
        defxworking = True

    elif mathsign != str():

        current = str(is_int(secondnum)) + "^"
        screen.set(current)
        defxworking = True


def result():
    global firstnum, secondnum, mathsign, current, power, defxworking, percentt
    if defxworking == False and percentt == False:
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum + secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum - secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "*":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum * secondnum), 6)
        if mathsign == "/":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum / secondnum), 6)
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))

    if mathsign == str() and defxworking == True and percentt == False:
        firstnum = round(firstnum ** int(power), 6)
        defxworking = False
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))

    if mathsign != str() and defxworking == True and percentt == False:
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(firstnum + secondnum ** int(power), 6)
            defxworking = False
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(firstnum - secondnum ** int(power), 6)
            defxworking = False
        if mathsign == "*":
            firstnum = round(firstnum * (secondnum ** int(power)), 6)
            defxworking = False
        if mathsign == "/":
            firstnum = round(firstnum / (secondnum ** int(power)), 6)
            defxworking = False
        screen.set(is_int(firstnum))

    if defxworking == False and percentt == True:
        if mathsign == "+":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum + firstnum / 100 * secondnum), 6)
            screen.set(is_int(firstnum))
            percentt = False
        if mathsign == "-":
            firstnum = round(float(firstnum - firstnum / 100 * secondnum), 6)
            screen.set(is_int(firstnum))
            percentt = False

    mathsign = str()
    current = ""
    power = ""

    if defxworking == False and mathsign == "*" or "/" and percentt == True:
        clear()


def clear():
    global current, firstnum, secondnum, mathsign, power, defxworking, percentt

    screen.set(0)
    current = ""
    power = ""
    firstnum = str()
    secondnum = str()
    mathsign = str()
    defxworking = False
    math_button_raised()
    percentt = False


def percent():
    global firstnum, secondnum, current, percentt

    current = str(is_int(secondnum)) + "%"
    screen.set(current)
    percentt = True


def press(num):
    if button_toggle.config("text")[-1] == "ON":
        global expression

        expression = expression + str(num)

        equation.set(expression)


def equalpress():
    try:

        global expression

        total = str(eval(expression))

        equation.set(total)

        expression = ""

    except:

        equation.set(" error ")
        expression = ""


def clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    equation.set("")


def Simpletoggle():
    if button_toggle.config("text")[-1] == "ON":
        button_toggle.config(text="OFF")
        for button in all_buttons:
            button.config(state="normal")
            screen.set(current)
    else:
        button_toggle.config(text="ON")
        for button in all_buttons:
            button.config(state="disabled")
            screen.set("")

def clear():
    global current, firstnum, secondnum, mathsign, power, defxworking, percentt

    screen.set(0)
    current = ""
    power = ""
    firstnum = str()
    secondnum = str()
    mathsign = str()
    defxworking = False
    math_button_raised()
    percentt = False

    def __init__(self):
        self.total = 0
        self.current = ""
        self.new_num = True
        self.op_pending = False
        self.op = ""
        self.eq = False

def backspace(self):
   self.current = self.current[:-1]
   if self.current == "":
      self.new_num = True
      self.current = "0"



calculation = Entry(root, textvariable=screen, font=("Verdana", 15, ), bd=12, insertwidth=4, width=14, justify=RIGHT,)
calculation.grid(columnspan=4)

button1 = Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: number_pressed(1), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button1.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

button2 = Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: number_pressed(2), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)

button3 = Button(root, text="3", command=lambda: number_pressed(3), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button3.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)

button4 = Button(root, text="4", command=lambda: number_pressed(4), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button4.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

button5 = Button(root, text="5", command=lambda: number_pressed(5), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button5.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)

button6 = Button(root, text="6", command=lambda: number_pressed(6), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button6.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)

button7 = Button(root, text="7", command=lambda: number_pressed(7), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button7.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

button8 = Button(root, text="8", command=lambda: number_pressed(8), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button8.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)

button9 = Button(root, text="9", command=lambda: number_pressed(9), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button9.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=W)

button0 = Button(root, text="0", command=lambda: number_pressed(0), bg="gainsboro",
                 bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button0.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)

button_float = Button(root, text=".", command=lambda: number_pressed("."), bg="gainsboro",
                      bd=3, padx=15, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button_float.grid(row=5, column=1)

button_plus = Button(root, text="+", command=lambda: math_pressed("+"), bg="gray",
                     bd=3, padx=11, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button_plus.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)

button_minus = Button(root, text="-", command=lambda: math_pressed("-"), bg="gray",
                      bd=3, padx=11, pady=4, font=("Verdana", 14, "bold"))
button_minus.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W)

button_multiply = Button(root, text="*", command=lambda: math_pressed("*"), bg="gray",
                         bd=3, padx=13, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button_multiply.grid(row=4, column=3)

button_division = Button(root, text="/", command=lambda: math_pressed("/"), bg="gray",
                         bd=3, padx=14, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button_division.grid(row=5, column=3)

button_equal = Button(root, text="=", command=lambda: result(), bg="gray70",
                      bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 14))
button_equal.grid(row=5, column=2)

button_percent = Button(root, text="%", command=lambda: percent(), bg="gray",
                        bd=3, padx=8, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button_percent.grid(row=1, column=3)

button_toggle = Button(root, text="OFF", command=Simpletoggle, bg="gray",
                       bd=3, padx=6, pady=6, font=("Helvetica", 12))
button_toggle.grid(row=1, column=0)

button_sqrt = Button(root, text="√", command=lambda: squareroot(), bg="gray",
                     bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14, "bold"))
button_sqrt.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)

button_x = Button(root, text="x^y", command=lambda: x(), bg="gray",
                  bd=3, padx=6, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 14))
button_x.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

button_clear = Button(root, text='CLEAR', command=lambda: clear(), bg='gray',
                      bd=3, padx=12, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 16))
button_clear.grid(row=6, columnspan=2)

button_backspace = Button(root, text='BACK', command=lambda: backspace() , bg='gray',
                      bd=3, padx=15, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 16))
button_backspace.grid(row=6, column=2, columnspan=2)


all_buttons = [
    button1,
    button2,
    button3,
    button4,
    button5,
    button6,
    button7,
    button8,
    button9,
    button0,
    button_float,
    button_plus,
    button_minus,
    button_multiply,
    button_division,
    button_equal,
    button_percent,
    button_sqrt,
    button_x,
    button_clear,
    button_backspace,
]

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: def backspace():
   ex = len(calculation.get())
   calculation.delete(ex-1)

button_backspace = Button(root, text='BACK', command=backspace, bg='gray',
                      bd=3, padx=15, pady=5, font=("Helvetica", 16))

Answer (score 1):

hello davoz this my code write for you :

```py
from tkinter import *

def back():
    y  = len(entry.get())
    entry.delete(y-1)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

entry = Entry(root)
entry.pack()

button = Button(root,text="back",command=back).pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].